# How to manage React Js to multiple page app not using routes?

Tags: laravel, reactjs, laravel-elixir

I want to implement react js to different pages of my website,
e.g
in home page, registration, login, etc.

all tutorial i have seen it only uses 1 app.js how can i achieve this 
to multi page app.

P.S i am using laravel elixir and i combine them into 1 main.js.

Answer (score 0):

Add a mounting point in the pages that you want your **React App** to be mounted.

*e.g.*

```
// main.js
ReactDOM.render(<App props={/* props from somewhere */}/>, document.getElementById('mountingPoint') );

// rendered HTML from pages should have
<div id="mountingPoint"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://github.com/christianalfoni/react-webpack-cookbook/wiki/Multiple-entry-points

I think this is more appropriate on what i need and then i will just map the file
name in my laravel app.

this way i dont need to load the js code for contact_us.php to login.php

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something like [React Habitat](https://github.com/DeloitteDigitalAPAC/react-habitat) to make this architecture easier.

With it, you could just define a container of your components so they resolve in your DOM.

For example, in your javascript you would do

```
import MyComponent from './Components/MyComponent';

...

container.register(MyComponent).as(myComponent);
```

Then in any of your HTML pages

```
<div data-component="myComponent"></div>
```

It also supports multiple containers and async code splitting.